# Trouble with security.yml access_control

Tags: security, symfony, roles

I add some rules to access_control like this:

```
    - { path: ^/entity/create, role: ROLE_CREATE }
    - { path: ^/entity/.*/delete, role: ROLE_DELETE }
    - { path: ^/entity/.*/update, role: ROLE_EDIT }
    - { path: ^/entities, role: ROLE_VIEW }
```

But user with any of these roles can't access the entity. If I add ROLE_ADMIN

```
    - { path: ^/entities, roles: [ANY_ROLE, ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

than only admin get access, symfony ignores second role.

isGranted function returns false

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_VIEW') === false
```

But `$user->hasRole('ROLE_VIEW')` returns true

What is wrong with my roles?

Comment: Did you define `role_hierarchy` ?

Comment: Which hierarchy am I need? I have only admin hierarchy, like
   ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_MODERATOR
etc

Comment: Well, ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_CREATE, ROLE_DELETE ... ([doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles))

Comment: Found the solution! All roles must starts with ROLE_ prefix. I have some roles with GROUP_ prefix